# How can i copy data from one dynamo db table and append in another table without using script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to copy data from one dynamo db table and append in another table with same columns, data is in large size so lambda cannot be used.

Data is more than 20gb in size and stored in s3 in csv format. I am going to use DMS service to move data to dynamo db but DMS creates new table and i want data in the old table.

Answer (score 0):

Even with DMS you must use a script, it just allows you to create the script in an abstract way using rules and mappings.

You should use AWS Glue for this. Yes there's a script but it's 10 lines of simple python. You can read from S3 and use the DynamoDB connector to write to an existing table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb

#### Example

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# From S3
dynamicFrame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://s3path"]},
    format="csv",
    format_options={
        "withHeader": True,
        # "optimizePerformance": True,
    },
)

# To DynamoDB
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=dynamicFrame,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "MyTable",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)

job.commit()
```